# Android button too low

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a quiz application on Android and I have an issue with one of my layout. When there is too much text (but the text fit in the button), the button is too low.

I don't know how to fix it, I tried to increase the buttons height, decrease the size but it doesn't change anything. Is it possible to fix the position ?

Here is my layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:minHeight="30sp"
        android:progress="100"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:progressTint="#2f9926"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="#636262"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/caviardreamsbold"
        android:id="@+id/tv_no"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="400sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/caviardreams"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="450sp"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/img"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="160sp"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/button_multiple"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="160sp"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/button_multiple"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30sp">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="160sp"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/button_multiple"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btn_three"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="160sp"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/button_multiple"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btn_four"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot because it's hard to explain clearly :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/10/6/1552145596-screenshot-20190309-162509.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to the LinearLayouts

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` will set your text to the center of your view - this is what it does

Comment: Yes but I don't really understand why it fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) - it will make the text on your view to resize according to the amount of text:

**In your gradle:**

```
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
```

**And now just put it in your XML:**

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="12sp"
app:minTextSize="8sp" />
```

**Edit** - I noticed that you are using fixed size on your view, first use sp as text size and not vire size and second don't use fixed sizes in your layout because your layout will just not be responsive, instead use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)    like this :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.BookMenu.BookMenu">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:minHeight="30sp"
    android:progress="100"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#636262"
    android:progressTint="#2f9926"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_question"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/img"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_no"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_no" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="153dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_two"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_two"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_two"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_two" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_two"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="347dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/img"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressbar" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_three"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_one"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_four"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_four"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_one" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_four"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_two"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/img"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_two"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it wasn't what I was looking for because there was enough space in the button to fill the text but the button was too low. Adam fixed my problem.

Comment: @Morgane glad you found your answer - I have edited mine because I saw that your layout is not responsive, have a look at my answer anyway.

Comment: Oh thanks, yes I'm not very familiar with Android yet. I thought about creating more xml files for the different screen sizes. However I can't see the preview layout, I got an error with your code about BookMenu and even if I delete it the preview doesn't display.

Comment: It would be the best to just use constraintLayout - you should learn it, very easy to use